# Python creating a cumulative score counter using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a prisoners dilemma game where two (variables) players work together. If one player betrays and the other cooperates, the betraying player gets 5 points and the other gets 0. If they both work together they both get 3 points, and if they both betray each other they get 1 point each.

How do I in the form of a for loop create a cumulative score counter for both players? The game should be able to play several times (until the players quit). How do I best set this up? So far I have been able to make a counter for each individual game, but not able to keep track of the scores across several rounds...

Code so far:

```
def game():
#Task 1
player_1 = input('Name of player 1 ')
player_2 = input('Name of player 2 ')

#Set up options for prisoners dilemma for players + give them choice
print(player_1)
choice_player_1 = input('betray or cooperate? ')
print(player_2)
choice_player_2 = input('betray or cooperate? ')


#Establish a score count
count1 = 0
count2 = 0



#If statement som skiller de ulike kombinasjonene som kan oppstå
if choice_player_1 == 'cooperate' and choice_player_2 == 'betray':
    count2 += 5

elif choice_player_1 ==  'cooperate' and choice_player_2 == 'betray':
    count1 += 5

elif choice_player_1 == 'cooperate' and choice_player_2 == 'betray':
    count1 += 3
    count2 += 3

elif choice_player_1 == 'betray' and choice_player_2 == 'betray':
    count1 += 1
    count2 += 1

    #Tally the points 
print(player_1, 'you got', count1, 'points', player_2, 'you got', count2, 'points')

print('Start the program again if you want to play another round ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create new variables in which after each match it happends the results of the single game. Does it make sense or I did not understand you problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing each value individually, you could compare [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples). If you map these tuples to the resulting scores as tuples, you will obtain a short but readable snippet like this:

```
points_table = {
    ("cooperate", "betray"   ): (0, 5),
    ("betray"   , "cooperate"): (5, 0),
    ("cooperate", "cooperate"): (3, 3),
    ("betray",    "betray"   ): (1, 1),
}

count1 = 0
count2 = 0
while running:
    choice_player_1 = input('betray or cooperate? ')
    choice_player_2 = input('betray or cooperate? ')
    round_count1, round_count2 = points_table[(choice_player_1, choice_player_2)]
    count1 += round_count1
    count2 += round_count2
```

Comment: What do I do if "running' is not defined?

Comment: @DaniloGleichmann That's just a variable that you need to define yourself. Make it `True` for as long as the loop should run.